# Unit testing Angular 2 JS code without using browser and Karma test runner

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, typescript, jasmine

I am trying to execute the unit test cases from [QuickStart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/archive/master.zip) Seed from Angular official site.

I want to start using only Jasmine for unit testing so I have removed karma references from the project. The 'app.component.spec.ts' containing unit test cases is compiled fine to JS (using Gulp task), however, when I try to execute them I am getting below error:

```
 var /** @type {?} */ meta = Reflect.getOwnMetadata('propMetadata', target.constructor) || {};
                                                    ^

TypeError: Reflect.getOwnMetadata is not a function
    at PropDecorator (node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:463:53)
    at __decorate (app.component.js:5:110)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.component.js:23:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Though haven't tried, it would work fine with Karma set up as provided in QuickStart seed.

However, it would helpful to know why doesn't work with only Jasmine? Also, is there any other JS library need to be imported for making it work.

Current app.component.spec.ts: (again same as seed)

```
import { AppComponent } from '../app/app.component';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
 
describe('AppComponent', function () {
    let de: DebugElement;
    let comp: AppComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [AppComponent]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h1'));
    });

    it('should create component', () => expect(comp).toBeDefined());

    it('should have expected <h1> text', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const h1 = de.nativeElement;
        expect(h1.innerText).toMatch(/angular/i,
            '<h1> should say something about "Angular"');
    });
});
```

**Update:**
The method causing errors is defined in ES7/reflect. I have added the required imports (Thanks @peeskillet for help). The updated test spec looks like below:

```
import '../node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min';
import 'core-js/es6';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import '../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';    

import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent, secondCmp } from '../app/app.component';

import {
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());

describe('1st tests', () => {
    it('true is true', () => expect(true).toBe(true));
});

describe('AppComponent1', function () {
    let de: DebugElement;
    let comp: AppComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [AppComponent, secondCmp]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        console.log(AppComponent.toString());
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#welcome'));
    });

    it('should create component', () => expect(comp).toBeDefined());

    it('should have setup success text', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const h1 = de.nativeElement;
        expect(h1.innerText).toContain('setup is successful');
    });
});
```

Now, I'm getting below error at TestBed.createComponent:

```
 ReferenceError: document is not defined
 Stack:
    ReferenceError: document is not defined
        at BrowserDomAdapter.defaultDoc (node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\bundles\platform-browser.umd.js:2015:71)
```

However, the above tests works fine with Karma test runner.

It looks like, the angular unit cases require document object which would be available in user agent like browser.

So, my question is browser is always required for executing Angular unit test cases?

Comment: All the [tests linked in the Angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#live-examples) are pure Jasmine tests. See what you're missing. We can't tell with the lack of information you've provided.

Comment: @peeskillet I don't find anything missing. I'm using [QuickStart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/archive/master.zip), it doesn't work even without any modifications

Comment: Why do you think it (the quickstart) should work without modification? Did you look at the linked examples? It does require some modification from when you're using karma. Look at the first example link. It is the bare bones minimum. You should be able to see what you need.

Comment: Thanks for help, yes I tried your link, the very first test executes fine. It is once you start using `TestBed.configureTestingModule` the error in question above appears

Comment: Look at the `browser-test-shim`. This is like the `karma-test-shim` in the quickstart. You will need to add this file to the test file. This is mainly what I was referring to when I told you to check what you're missing.

Comment: Also make sure you have all the scripts in the test file. You might want to look at one of the examples that actually does an Angular test. The very first one deosn't